# Gmail Api - Push notifications

Tags: uwp, gmail-api

I'm building test UWP application which using Gmail API (simple gmail client).
So, I want to ask about possibility to receiving notification when my Inbox is changed?

Thanks.

Comment: May I know which library are you using for Gmail?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't used any library.  For Authentication I've used WebAuthenticationBroker out of the box. For calling API endpoints default HttpClient

Comment: Creating a subscription will help you for Push Notifications as mentioned in the link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push. Please refer the following link.

Comment: Thanks for the article

Comment: Did it solved your problem?